# nashorn call java from script 4 hour I did not expect to waste

Tags: nashorn

This works:

```
interpreter.eval("var myCls = Java.type('java.io.File');\n"+"myCls.createTempFile('nashorn','.tmp');", sc1 );
```

But this does not:

```
interpreter.eval("var myCls = Java.type('mypkg.MyClass');\n"+"myCls.play('misty');", sc1 );
```

Why?

P

Comment: The error message is ScriptException: TypeError: myCls.play is not a function in <eval> btw

Answer (score 0):

Okay after 6 or so hours of faffing, it turns out that
not only does the method need to be public and static, the
class itself needs to be public.

More relevant error messages would be nice.